# Flash Builder 4 auto import not working

Tags: flash, flash-builder, code-hinting

The code hinting works, but when I select the suggested code and press enter it does not auto import.. What might be the problem of this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Flash builder only auto imports when you use the keyword 'new'

so if type 'Math.PI' nothing happens, but if you type 'new Math' using auto complete then it does the importing for you

you can just type 'new whatever' then delete it if you don't need it

Comment: It also works when you add a variable, for example `var b:M...` and autocomplete to Math. I've been using that, but new might be quicker!